# When encrypting connection strings does the version of aspnet_regiis matter?

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

I have connection strings for a bunch of applications that i need to encrypt. I was reading that for a server farm I need to create a key and export to the other machines.

My question is which version of aspnet_regiis should i use. There is one for each version of .net that is loaded on the server.

Does the version you use need to match the apps .net version?

Example. I have 2 apps that are .net 4.5 and the other apps are still version 2.
Can i use the 4.5 version to do all of the encryption or do i use 4.5 on the 4.5 apps?

Do i need to have a set of keys for each .net version??

Answer (score 0):

Nope, doesn't matter which version you use to encrypt. The encryption algorithm is not version specific.